# A way to encode Unicode characters using ASCII

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, encoding, character-encoding

I have this code:

```
' Connects to the server
Dim _tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets._tcpClient
_tcpClient.Client.Connect(server, port)
' Open network stream
Dim _headerToSend As String = "POST evpost HTTP/1.0"... ' CityName = Čelpěkéy
Dim _networkStream As NetworkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream
Dim bytesToSend As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_headerToSend)
' Send the text to tcp server
_networkStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length)
```

I'm trying to save the value "**Čelpěkéy**" intro the DB, actually is saved but as "**Celpekéy**". This is because I'm using `Encoding.ASCII` and those characters are not supported by ASCII.

Considerations:

- The other side is a "Black Box", so if I change the encoding it would not work (e.g. `Encoding.Unicode`).
- The column in DB is an *nvarchar*. If I modify this field directly the value "Čelpěkéy" is correctly saved.
- The characters needed are these: http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cz.htm.

**Update**

Do you know any trick that allow me to still use ASCII encoding to save Unicode characters?

or

Do you believe this is not possible by using ASCII encoding?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` or the UTF8 version, not the ASCII version.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, sorry for not to mention it on the original question but the other side is a "black box" and doing that change does not work.

Comment: @Coyolero - You'll never get the desired result using ASCII encoding.  Something else must be causing the problem if not your encoding selection.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - You are right, so I think this could not be fixed without changing the encoding in the other side.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function DECODE(ByVal x As String) As String
        If x IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim b As Byte() = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetBytes(x)
            Return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b)
        Else
            Return x
        End If
End Function
```

1250 is the code number for East Europe (Romania). So 'Ceauşescu' will be translate 'Ceausescu'

Use a code specific for your country.